# Google Analytics: Mark some visitors to filter them later in analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

Is it possible mark some visitors, so that later i can able to filter them in analytics reports?

Manager asked me if it's possible to view which users payed for services and from where did they come.

I know that this is all possible without analytics. But why bother with it if there is already free and good solution like Google Analytics? :)

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can set custom variables with Google Analytics. You can then report on the custom variables.